# Are high bypass turbo jet engines suitable for tail and body mounted engines

Tags: jet-engine, turbofan

Are high bypass turbo jet engines suitable for tail and body mounted engines.  If not what are the drawbacks, danger if so, are there any anycraft with any such setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it depends on what you call 'high-bypass'. The RB.211 engine was tested in a tail mount on a [VC-10](https://www.vc10.net/History/Individual/XR809.html):

[image]

For tail-mounted high-bypass engines, the engine mount gets long, which means it gets heavy.

Tail- and bodymounted engines in general have drawbacks that also apply to high-bypass engines:

- the high position means maintenance access requires special equipment and takes longer
- for bodymounted engines, engine choices are limited by the amount of space available (unless you redesign this part of the fuselage, which can get expensive)